# Error while using Chocolatey to uprade my dart-sdk to latest version dart 3.0

Tags: powershell, dart, chocolatey

Today I just tried to upgrade my dart-sdk to the latest version by using Chocolatey package manager but I got this error . If access to those files are forbidden for my URL then what I can do ?[dart-sdk upgrade error with shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrcVL.jpg)

I use some other countries proxy many time ,but it didn't work out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the error message as text to your question.

Comment: Can you download Dart directly from: https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive ? It works fine here in Denmark.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance but I just need to change the DNS settings before working with chocolaty.